# Unable to type in textbox after editing a value in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to edit a text field but I am unable to type. When I am adding a user, It's working fine but in editing It's not working.

Here is my code -

```
const initialState = {
    name: "",
    age: 0
  };
const [state, setState] = useState<any>(initialState);
{ selectedUser ? 
    (<form className="form-inline">
        <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={state.name} onChange={onUpdateValue} />
        <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onUpdateValue} value={state.age} />
            
        <button type="submit" onClick={onUpdate} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Update</button>
    </form>)
    :
    (
        <form className="form-inline">
        <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={state.name} onChange={onChangeValue} />
        <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onChangeValue} value={state.age} />
            
        <button type="submit" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Submit</button>
    </form>
    )
    }
                    
                <button type="submit" onClick={onUpdate} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Update</button>
            </form>
```

And below is my onUpdateValue code -

```
const onUpdateValue = (event:any) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setState((prevState:any) => (
        { ...prevState, [name]: value }
        ));
    }
```

And below code for onChangeValue code -

```
const onChangeValue = (event:any) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setState((prevState:any) => (
            { ...prevState, [name]: value }
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Where do you update the value? You need to update the value in the `state` for it be rendered

Comment: Please check I have updated the question.

Comment: Why use two different functions that do exactly the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the react state for it to render the change:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState()
  const [age, setAge] = useState()

  const onUpdateValue = (event:any) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    console.log(name , value , "name-vlue")
    if (name === 'name') {
      setName(value)
    } else {
      setAge(value)
    }
  }

  const onUpdate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();     <==== Check this
    // do what you want here
  }

  return (
    <form className="form-inline">
      <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="email2" placeholder="Enter user name" name="name" value={selectedUser.name} onChange={onUpdateValue} />
      <input type="text" className="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-5 col-md-4" id="pwd2" placeholder="Enter user age" name="age" onChange={onUpdateValue} value={selectedUser.age} />
      <button type="submit" onClick={onUpdate} className="btn btn-primary col-md-2 mb-2">Update</button>
    </form>
  )
}
```

Check this please: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-keller-84k4n?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in the codesandbox I added?

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: You need to send the new Url of the sandbox!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-lederberg-8kjkf?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: This seems to work for me:
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-wind-1p5xs?file=/src/Test.js

Comment: But suppose we have props as selectedUser Then we need to update the state. How can we do that ? If we don't have props as selectedUser Then we are successfully able to change state & dispatch but In case of edit (we have props) then state change not wworking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222000/discussion-between-anurag-mishra-and-tasos-bu).